# GPIO mapping for Expressif esp8266 dev kit c

Tags: nodemcu

I am new to Lua, NodeMCU, and especially the Expressif esp8266 Dev Kit C.

I am able to build a firmware and flash it to the dev kit, as well as a Wemos D1 mini.

But when it comes to the simples GPIO examples and tests (blinking LED), I can run it on my Wemos D1 but not on the Expressif ESP8266 Dev Kit. For the Wemos the GPIO mapping given in the [NodeMCU gpio](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/gpio/) documentation works fine, but I seem to be unable to find the right mapping for my ExpressIf kit.

For that, I am using the [sp8266 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) to find a suitable GPIO pin, lookup its function and then use the mapping in the NodeMCU gpio docs to find the index to drive the GPIO pin.

Example:
ESP8266 pin: 16 --> ESP8266 pin function: GPIO4 --> NodeMCU ESP8266 pin: GPIO4 --> NodeMCU IO index: 2

I then connect the LED (anode to pin 16, cathode to a GND pin) and run the script - but nothing happens, even though the script runs happily...

The output shows the expected 'running...' followed by 'high' and 'low' alternating with a 1s frequency.

Script:

```
-- Config
local pin = 2            --> GPIO4
local value = gpio.LOW
local duration = 1000    --> 1 second

-- Function toggles LED state
function toggleLED ()
    if value == gpio.LOW then
        value = gpio.HIGH
        print("high")
    else
        value = gpio.LOW
        print("low")
    end
    gpio.write(pin, value)
end

-- Initialise the pin
gpio.mode(pin, gpio.OUTPUT)

-- Create an interval
local timer = tmr.create()
timer:alarm(duration, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, toggleLED)

print("running")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you derive the pin number. If you use the pin labeled as "12" on the ESP8266-DevKitC I would expect you have to use `local pin = 6` (as per the NodeMCU documentation) in your script.

Comment: Pin 12 in the datasheet (Table 2-1, link above) is named MTCK, an I/O pin, and has the function GPIO13. In the NodeMCU documentation, GPIO12 is indexed as 7, not 6.

Answer (score 0):

Marcel's comment got me onto the right path:

ESP8266's pin 12 is a GPIO pin, but I must't use the function description (GPIO 13) but the pin's number (i.e. 12) to look up the correct index number in NodeMCU documentation.

So, the correct index number for ESP8266's pin 16 is 0, not 2:

```
-- Config
local pin = 4            --> GPIO4
...
```